# Best way to pass arrays as command line arguments?

Tags: c, arrays, command-line-arguments

I want to be able to pass an array as a command line argument/option argument, i.e., when the program is run with e.g., `-a [1,2,3]` I want the option argument to be parsed as an array of size 3 with elements 1,2,3. The array is of arbitrary length (within reasonable limits). The syntax may be defined differently if that leads to a more convenient solution - the above is just an example which I consider natural.

Obviously, one can strip away the `[]` brackets, split the string by `,`and then parse each number with `atoi`/`strtol` and pack it into an array, but I am wondering whether there is an easier way to achieve this.

**Edit:** I want to be able to pass multiple arrays. So using `./main 1 2 3` is not an option.

Comment: `argv` is already an array. Why don't you just space-separate the arguments? You could interpret the elements of `argv` enclosed between two dash-options as "arrays" or parameter lists.

Comment: The issues is primarily one of how the command line interpretor parse user input.  Typically spaces dominate the separation in to arguments.  But quotes may over-ride.  "1 2 3" may be 1 argument.  IMO, your original proposal is good.

Comment: Like I said, the format may be changed - and there isn't a big difference between "1 2 3" and [1,2,3] anyway.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: This would require the same work, minus stripping and splitting the argument string,

Comment: If your main question is the title of the question, using `"1 2 3 "` as the command line argument is the best. It's simplest to type in the command line. It's easiest to parse in a C/C++ program.

Comment: Lets say you have 2 arguments in your command line(argc =2) first is the number of elements in the array and the second is a string which you can parse and just fetch numbers and add them to array doesn't this look simple?

Comment: @mort and so what's the problem? Is it not good that someone (the shell) has already done the work for you?

Comment: If you want a general solution you'll have to write a little parser for what argv sees. It would be easier to do this not in C but in a language that can self evaluate like perl, python or LISP